# Compiler fingerprint in object

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

I just spent the better part of a day trying to figure out why I was getting the error:

> Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

Turns out that one of my third party packages (Apache Log4CXX) was compiled with Visual Studio 2013 (VC120) and my application was compiled with Visual Studio 2015.  The build was accidentally pulling DLLs from the the wrong library.

The debug_heap uses a different format for the memory header between the two (thus the invalid _block_use) and bad things happen when you attempt to release memory.

Now for the question, I know Java has the compiler's version number compiled into it's class files (yah Java).  Does Visual Studio mark it's object, lib or dll files with some sort of fingerprint that identified what version of Visual C++ compiled the file?

I've tried dumping out the headers with dumpbin and objdump but nothing stands out as a compiler fingerprint.

Comment: Third party component was also built with debug settings (debug allocator)?

Comment: Yes.  The issue was definitely due to the compiler mismatch, I ran through the code with the disassembler until I found the problem in the header.  I am aware of the problems when mixing Debug and Release code, that was the first thing I checked.

Comment: Are you allocating memory on one module and freeing / reallocating it in another? Even with the same version of the compiler, how is it supposed to work?

Comment: @VladFeinstein It works if all modules use the same version and flavor of CRT DLL (as opposed to linking to CRT statically). Then, they all share the same heap manager.

Comment: Right, the question has to do with being able to verify that I have the right DLLs